# Fancy part title page with titleformat and centering problem

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, titlesec, parts

I would like to create a fancy part title page but I have some issues with `titleformat`.
Currently, I use :

```
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter\thispagestyle{empty}}
{}{0pt}{
\LARGE\color{nicedarkblue}
\adforn{49}\qquad\adforn{11}\qquad\adforn{21}
\scshape\Huge\color{nicedarkblue}
\linebreak
#1
\linebreak
\LARGE\color{nicedarkblue}
\adforn{21}\qquad\adforn{11}\qquad\adforn{49}
}[]
```

and it produces:

[image: partproblem]

How to :

- center the whole thing on the page (vertically)
- adds "Première partie`\linebreak`" (first part in french), "Deuxième partie`\linebreak`" (second part in french) in case of `\part`just before the title of the part
- optionally adds a quote (epigraph) after the whole thing

Comment: \null\vfil usually works for me.

Comment: Please provide a ***complete*** minimal working example. That is a lot easier to work with than a fragment requiring people to first guess relevant parts of your preamble.

Comment: Are thre any news here? We have still not seen a minimal working example. The second part of your question is completly unclear to me. Please explain yourself by means of a MWE as requested before.